# Why do I get 3 errors with this code in particular?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, sleep

```
    if (answer == "help") {
        for (int i = 0; i < enterCommand.length; i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(help[i]);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
```

The errors I get are:

- Multiple markers at this line

  - Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete 
    IfStatement
  - help cannot be resolved to a variable
  - Syntax error on token "if", ( expected after this 
    token

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: please display the entire code with error

Comment: Is this code inside a method?

Comment: You are probably missing a closing '"' above the shown code! Further on, your string comparison is not what it should be. It should look like if ("help".equals(answer))...

Comment: No... No.. :__( It's the second time I see `== vs equals` today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code is not complete to its just a guess game to answer correctly.

Looks like you are comparing two stings in "if" statement.
instead of == use .equals method like:

```
if ( answer.equals("help") ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < enterCommand.length; i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(help[i]);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

} // end of for
} // end of if
```

Hopefully this will solve your query and then check the output.....otherwise post complete code again.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined a variable called `help`.

You are not closing the if block using ending bracket `}`

Apart from these syntax error, another problem is you are comparing a string using `==`. String should be compared using equals method.

```
   if (answer == "help")
```

should be replaced with

```
   if ("help".equals(answer) )
```

**Advice**: Don't jump into coding without learning the basic constructs of programming. So read the basics first to avoid too much of struggle.

Comment: I welcome negative votes with comment. So please be kind to me to provide your valuable comments.

Comment: Thanks, this was also helpful but I feel the other one provided more info. I will consult the basics again, as I haven't done java in a while...